# AngularJS karma -- Unable to initiate unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write sample unit test for angular controller. But test fails with error message :

```
  Error: Unknown provider: $$rAFProvider from ngMock
        at Error (native)
        at c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:28:338
        at Object.c [as get] (c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:26:104)
        at Object.j.$provide.decorator (c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:28:217)
        at c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular-mocks.js:1746:12
        at Object.d [as invoke] (c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:26:320)
        at c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:25:107
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at m (c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:193)
        at e (c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:24:398)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'testName' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (c:/eclipse/workspace/Ecomm-Fron-End/WebContent/js/assets/test/sample.js:18:18)
```

My sample test case was :

```
describe('Unit: homeCtrl', function() {
  // Load the module with MainController
  beforeEach(module('yourMarketApp'));

   var ctrl, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('homeCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

   it('should test scope.testName', 
    function() {
        expect(scope.testName).toEqual("");
  });

});
```

I have already checked , angular and angular mock file versions are same(v1.2.19)

Comment: are you  missing any dependencies like `angular-animate.js` or something similar ? can you post your karma config ?

Comment: No, I am not missing any of them

Comment: Can you post your `homeCtrl` source?